# Is it possible to use proguard with Grails

Tags: java, grails, proguard

Even if it is not possible to use proguard for an entire grails app would it be possible to just use it for the src/java folder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know either Proguard or Grails in depth, but I do know that:

1. Grails uses Groovy
2. Groovy compiles down to bytecode
3. Proguard [operates on bytecode](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#FAQ.html) (not source code)

Thus my intuition is yes, ProGuard can shrink/obfuscate grails apps.  Your question asks about using ProGuard on the src/java folder. It's important to understand that ProGuard operates on .class files, not .java files.  A correct configuration will need to operate on your bin directory, not src.  Unfortunately I'm not qualified to give you a detailed example configuration, but I hope this gets you on the right path.