# Can we implement ProGuard within our Grails project?

Tags: grails, groovy, proguard, obfuscation

I'm bringing this topic back after reading the following post on Stackoverflow as there was no answer:

[Is it possible to use proguard with Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897426/is-it-possible-to-use-proguard-with-grails)

It's clear that Grails is using Groovy and Groovy compiles the code down to bytecode. And Proguard also uses bytecode....

So has anyone tried to do this? Or maybe there is an alternative method which I'm missing?

Comment: As long as it compiles into a jar file you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, but how is it done? :)

Comment: have you tried adding the dependency (haven't tried it myself) to build.gradle ? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.proguard/proguard/4.4  compile group: 'net.sf.proguard', name: 'proguard', version: '4.4'

Comment: What do you mean by "how is it done"? Are you asking how to set it up as part of the exporting process, or asking how proguard works?

Comment: As part of export process. For example, today I'm using grails prod war to generate the war.....